# How to receive a message from python and save it in php

Tags: php, python

This is my python code to send data

```
URL = 'https://example.com/'
import requests,json
def log(m):
    message = {'m': str(m)}
    r = requests.get(URL+'receive.php', params=message)
    return r.text

log ('Hello World')
```

Now I want to save the received messages in `log.html` file using `receive.php` file

Now I don't know the php side code. How to receive it and save it?

Comment: When you say don't know, do you mean it's there but you don't have the access to it? or you don't know how to code the PHP part and ask us to give you some reference?

Comment: I know php, but not excellent in it. I need some hint or something to know how to do it. Python is sending the data in get format, but how can I save that get data in a log file using php? I know, how to utilize get data when someone submit forms, but in form the page gets redirected to the php page and code executes, but here, idk what to do

Comment: wait a sec, when python sends data to `receive.php`, does the file (receive.php) execute the code? Let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the parameters to PHP variable the can be accessed by three array variables.

$_POST : you can access parameters in this array if the request made using post method.

$_GET : Similarly get request parameters can be accessed by this array.

$_REQUEST : Both post and get request parameters can be accessed by $_REQUEST array

```
<?php

$msg= $_REQUEST['m'];

if(file_put_contents('log.html', $msg , FILE_APPEND)){
  echo "Done";
}
else{
 echo "Error in file write.";
}


?>
```

Also you can access raw input like JSON data or text data which not in the key value format you can use `file_get_contents("php://input")` to access data